# Bash script works fine individually but NOT in a loop

Tags: bash

The script below works fine with individual input from the command prompt:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

#This script determines namespaces with or without pods in it. 

namespace=$1
kubectl get pods -n "$namespace" > pod_list.txt
if ! grep -q NAME pod_list.txt; then
    echo pods not found
else
    echo pods found
fi
```

But when it is put on a loop basically reading line by line inputs from a text file it doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail
input="namespace.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo $line
    kubectl get pods -n "$line" > pod_list.txt
    if grep -q NAME pod_list.txt; then
        echo $line pods NOT found >> pod.txt
    else
        echo $line pods found >> pod.txt
    fi
done < "$input"
```

Could anybody please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess: What does `kubectl` do with standard input?

Comment: Try doing `while IFS= read -r -u 10 line ... done 10<"$input"`

Comment: @KamilCuk: Thanks but it didn't work. In this script kubectl lists the pods for kubernetes namespace.

Comment: Double post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67832583/bash-if-else-echo-separating-outcome.  Pick one, fix the code in that one.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how it “doesn’t work”? What goes wrong?